# How to write Exceptions into ULS Log using CSOM?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is there any way for logging the exceptions into ULS logs on sharepoint 2013 on-premise version? And it should be done using csom only.

Answer (score 1):

[SPDiagnosticsServiceBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase.aspx) is not available via CSOM.

Comment: Is there any other way to log(whether to sql table or list) those exceptions using CSOM?

Comment: If you manually log any encountered errors to a SharePoint List, you could use CSOM to enumerate that list.

Comment: Sorry to troubling you, As I'm new to SharePoint, can you pls explain how to log manually into list on SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://tech.bool.se/log-to-uls-using-javascript/

Although it appears to using SOAP, which I'm personally not fan of.

Comment: Thanks for your update.. Is there anyother way to achieve this using CSOM(not javascript)?